# how does amazon api requests per second work exactly?

Tags: c#, api, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

I am building a shop that will request items through Amazon API while you are running the app.

now as written [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html) I can only request 1 item per second. does that mean for certain IP? so if I have another device requesting using the same `AssociateTag` does that mean I am requesting double the amount? or each IP will be handled independently ?

Comment: It will look at the Access Key you are using, which will be the same for all running instances of your application. So you will have to pay them if you want more requests pr second from their api(s)

Comment: thanks. do you have any leads on more details about that like pricing? aws premium doesnt say anything about response per second.

Comment: found this using google [https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/) but it is not very helpful

Comment: Note that the documentation says 1 request per second. IIRC you can get more than one item in response to a request.

Comment: @MalteR The API gateway is an AWS service for scaling API calls, but it is not related to the ecommerce/retail API that the question asks for.

Comment: @user33003 For bulk data/product feeds, contact them through this page - https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/home/contact - and select subject as 'Product Feeds'. (Source - http://www.a2sdeveloper.com/page-does-amazoncom-offer-a-data-feed.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the troubleshooting guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html), maximum allowed request rate is 'once per second **per IP address**'.

If two devices on the same LAN, i.e. they are using same public IP, then I believe they will be limited to a total of one call per second.
If two devices have different public IP addresses, then as per the documentation, one request per second per device should be okay.

Now, one request can return multiple items (ItemSearch API returns 10 results in one API call - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html)